# UIViewController presenting and dismissing not animating

Tags: animation, uiviewcontroller

I don't understand why my calls to `presentViewController:animated:completion:` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` are not performing the animations (although `animated` is YES and I'm calling these methods from the main thread)...

The code is pretty simple:

```
ProjectRootViewController *projectViewController = [ProjectRootViewController.alloc initWithProject:project department:Department.defaultDepartment];
NavigationController *navigationController = [NavigationController.alloc initWithRootViewController:projectViewController];
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[viewController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's resolved! This was because a leak of memory due to a category on NSObject... My bad!